# How to wrap text in OpenCV when I print it on an image and it exceeds the frame of the image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have a 1:1 ratio image and I want to make sure that if the text exceeds the frame of the image, it gets wrapped to the next line.
How would I do it?

I am thinking of doing an if-else block, where "if sentence exceeds x characters->new line" but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('images/1.png')
print(img.shape)

height, width, channel = img.shape

text_img = np.ones((height, width))
print(text_img.shape)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
text = "Lorem Ipsum "
textsize = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, 2, 2)[0]

font_size = 1
font_thickness = 2
for i, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):

    textsize = cv2.getTextSize(line, font, font_size, font_thickness)[0]

    gap = textsize[1] + 10

    y = int((img.shape[0] + textsize[1]) / 2) + i * gap
    x = int((img.shape[1] - textsize[0]) / 2)

    cv2.putText(img, line, (x, y), font,
                font_size, 
                (0,0,0), 
                font_thickness, 
                lineType = cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("Result Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `textwrap` to wrap text in OpenCV.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import textwrap 

img = cv2.imread('apple.png')
print(img.shape)

height, width, channel = img.shape

text_img = np.ones((height, width))
print(text_img.shape)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

text = "Lorem Ipsum dgdhswjkclyhwegflhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhvhasvcxsbvfajhskvfgsdj"
wrapped_text = textwrap.wrap(text, width=35)
x, y = 10, 40
font_size = 1
font_thickness = 2

for i, line in enumerate(wrapped_text):
    textsize = cv2.getTextSize(line, font, font_size, font_thickness)[0]

    gap = textsize[1] + 10

    y = int((img.shape[0] + textsize[1]) / 2) + i * gap
    x = int((img.shape[1] - textsize[0]) / 2)

    cv2.putText(img, line, (x, y), font,
                font_size, 
                (0,0,0), 
                font_thickness, 
                lineType = cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("Result Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below is the output image without using `textwrap`(running your code):

[image]

Below is the output image using `textwrap`(my code):

[image]

There are many other ways you can achieve the same but `textwrap` is certainly one way of doing so in OpenCV and is simple too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anubhav!
This helped a lot!