# Set width of text using OpenCV (putText)

Tags: python, opencv

I am using openCV to edit some frames of a video file.

I am using putText to insert text in frames

I am stuck at a point where the width of the text exceeds the width of the frame

I have searched about it, but can't find any suitable solution over this platform yet

My code is followed as:

```
while(cap.isOpened()):

      ret, frame = cap.read()
      if ret==True:

            x = 0
            y = 478
            w = 640
            h = 40

            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
            font_color = (255, 255, 255)
            thick = 1
            text = "A very long text here blaaah blaaah blaaah blaaah blaaah blaaah . . . . . "
            font_size = 0.9
            (text_width, text_height) = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_size, thick)[0]

            if text_width > w :
                    # statements to fit width

            loc_x = x + int(w/2) - int(text_width/2)
            loc_y = y + int(h/2) + int(text_height/2)
            frame = cv2.putText(frame,text,(loc_x,loc_y),font,font_size,font_color,thick,cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.imwrite("frame.png",frame)
```

For example,

[image]

Also I don't want text to drop at next line, I wanted text should shrink in width in order to fit in the frame if it exceeds

I want to reduce ***WIDTH*** not ***HEIGHT***

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660627/9681220  maybe help you

Comment: @taherfattahi It seems that `textwrap` would try to fit in the page but it might bring my text to next line which i don't want, by the way, I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a blank NumPy array of the size of your text height and width (I had to add 15 to text height otherwise it the text was not coming properly) and put your text on it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('messi.jpg')
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
font_color = (255, 255, 255)
thick = 1
text = "A very long text here blaaah blaaah blaaah blaaah blaaah blaaah . . . . . "
font_size = 0.9
(text_width, text_height) = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_size, thick)[0]
text_height += 15

mask = np.zeros((text_height, text_width), dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.putText(mask,text,(0,15),font,font_size,font_color,thick,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

[image: mask1]

Now resize the width of this mask to your image width.

```
mask = cv2.resize(mask, (img.shape[1], text_height))
```

[image: mask_resized]

This text needs to be put on your original image which can be done via bitwise or, but before that we will need to make the mask have 3 channels as the dimensions should match. Use `cv2.merge` for this task.

```
mask = cv2.merge((mask, mask, mask))
img[-text_height:, :, :] = cv2.bitwise_or(img[-text_height:, :, :], mask)
```

[image: original image][image: result]

You can adjust it wherever you want just take care of the dimensions match.

Comment: Sorry for responding you so late, actually your code is really helpful, the problem is I am still figuring out how it works. Especially this last line `img[-text_height:, :, :] = cv2.bitwise_or(img[-text_height:, :, :], mask)`. I am new to OpenCV

Comment: Also buddy, could you please tell me why'd you use `text_height += 15`?? I have various text sample for different fonts, so I am figuring it out to make a general function for all of them

Comment: Bitwise or will take all the pixels one by one for both the arguments and choose the maximum value. Like if you know how logical or works. The mask has a smaller height compared to the original image. So we cannot straightaway apply bitwise or to mask and image as the dimensions should match. So we take only the part of the image which is required. Essentially the height should be equal to text height so we grab the area where we want to put the text using numpy indexing and apply bitwise or to only that part of the original image along with the mask to put text.

Comment: `text_height += 15` this was done as when I placed the text on mask created without doing this the text went out of bounds. So this was just to ensure that the whole text remains in bounds. As long as you are not changing the font size this should not matter. I had taken 15 arbitrary and it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much pal ! I got it, but my concern is with font size, I can't always use 15 as arbitrary constant. Anyway, for now my major problem is being solved because of you !

Comment: Well there is a roundabout to this problem. While making the mask make its height like 50 so any size of text can be easily placed. Write all your text in the middle. Now remove the empty rows above and below the text. This would remove the requirement of adding an arbitrary number like 15 and would work for all font sizes. If you can't code it let me know I'll do it and add it.

Comment: Thank you very much pal! For now, my major problem has been solved but in future I'll be working with other fonts. I will keep in mind about this solution, I'll surely let you know if I found any errors while coding.